# Running newer exe on older version in dot net

Tags: c#

I have prepared c# console application using VS 2010 framework 4.0 and have done exe of the same.I want to run the same exe on the other server where on vs 2005 (Framework 2.0) is installed.Is there any way to do the same ?

Comment: You need the .net 4 stack to develop against it. VS 2005 simply doesn't support it, so no, you can't develop using vs 2005, but if you install .net 4, you can run the app.

Comment: Yes, install .Net 4.0 on target machine. Or, if your program only uses .Net 2.0 then change your target framework

Answer (score 3):

Install the .NET 4.0 framework on the target PC. That's the most practical option.

Also, why is VS2005 on your server? Having an IDE on a server seems slightly "odd".

Without a more uptodate version of Visual Studio, you won't be able to develop/alter this application easily, but with the .NET4 framework on your machine you'll be able to run the executable.

Comment: If by "slightly odd" you mean "an amazingly bad idea" :)

Comment: Or recompile in VS 2010 and target 2.0.  If you haven't used any features that were introduced after 2.0, then it will work.

Comment: @David: Why would you consider it an "amazingly bad idea" to have VS installed on a server?

Comment: Yes, also a sensible idea... However since things like auto properties and initializers turned up after 2, there's a high degree of probability that it'll require rework.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - You should have development and test servers that mirror the live server as closely as possible. I'd imagine live servers would NOT have an IDE on them.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I guess it depends on what "server" means in this case.  The answerer and I both seem to have interpreted it as a target deployment server (production? even test wouldn't be good either), in which case development should never take place on that machine.  Having VS on a deployment server opens the door pretty wide to developers tinkering on a live system, bypassing all manner of controls over the code.  Development tools are for the development environment (local workstation, primarily), not for target deployment environments.

Comment: @David: Still, it doesn't break anything, does it? So I don't really see why it should be "an amazingly bad idea"... It is not best practice, sure, but it's not like it opens up any vulnerabilities, reduces performance etc. I just oppose to the label you gave it, IMHO it is too harsh.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: It might break something.  Just installing the development tools adds things to the machine that another target deployment server (such as production) wouldn't have.  This can quickly lead to "it works on my machine" syndrome.  From there it's a pretty short step to the developer not knowing why the application doesn't run on the target server and just recommending that VS (and other tools) be installed everywhere "just to make sure the application works."  This tightly couples the running application with the development tools, which is a terrible thing.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I guess my point is (in one last comment, since this thread doesn't add much to the answer) that target servers should have a whitelist approach instead of a blacklist approach.  It shouldn't be "this doesn't hurt anything, so why not install it?"  It should be "this doesn't accomplish anything, so don't install it."  There's no reason to have the IDE on a target server, it accomplishes nothing of use (without doing more harm than good in cases where it *looks like* it's useful).  Thus, it shouldn't be installed.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - Unless you have it on ALL your servers, what you do is then create deployment unpredictability as the machines are not equivalent in quite a significant way. This could cause you to accidentally break a deployment to live. I have seen this happen with older versions of Visual Studio on development servers working fine, then deploy to live and BANG Visual C runtime issue.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no. 
**However**, if your application can be built for .NET 2.0, you can make another build of it which will run on your server. In VS, Right click project > Application, change Target Framework.
[image: http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/multitarget/step6.jpg]

If you can, ***the best option would be installiing NET 4.0 on your server***, though. Note that it does not require upgrading VS2005 (which might or might not be an option). This eliminates the need of managing 2 sepparate builds for 2 different environments

Comment: Thanks Dragos, I have build application in 2.0 and placed on the server.Now on running exe it is saying that "devide is not ready." While building application I also set target machine as "ANY CPU"..Still it is showing he error?? Any idea please !!

Comment: I'm 99% sure this one hasn't got to do with the exe build in particular. Unfortunately it's a very vague error, may be from a number of causes. What is your application trying to do? anything related to hardware/device sdk/etc?

Comment: Yess Dragos, This error is resolved now. The paths given in the app.config were changed. Exe is runnig perfectly fine.Many thanks for your solution.